# How to fix Python 3.7 importing errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, visual-studio-code, sqlalchemy

I have a very simple question, well I have an instance of SQLAlchemy in my `__init__.py` file.

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

I am trying to import it all over my project but unsuccessfully.

```
from . import db
```

I appreciate your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this webpage:
https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html

Can you also provide your directory structure in your answer?

You should be able to use db directly in the other files if they are in the same directory without having to use the import

Answer (score 0):

I always hate importing in local modules and end up having to do something like this a lot of times:

```py
try:
  from package.module import thing
except ModuleNotFoundError:
  import os
  import sys
  here = os.path.realpath(__file__)
  root = os.path.split(here)[0]  # add more splits to dig deeper in your structure
  sys.path.append(root)
  from package.module import thing
```

I hope that helps.  Almost certainly not the "right" way to do it though.